# Strange web font issue?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts, website

[image]

Why is this happening? I'm using Windows 7 32bit with the latest stable Chrome build.

Comment: Odd - I don't see this problem in the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7. Does it occur in other browsers? Have you changed the default character encoding for your browser?

Comment: I don't have this problem with IE9. I have no idea what character encoding is so if u can tell me what the default is, I'll change it.

Comment: Does this happen on all websites or just this particular one?

Comment: I've seen it happen on another website before but I just ignored it. I assume they use the same character encoding.

Comment: See if it is a font item http://superuser.com/questions/355084/chrome-is-displaying-international-characters-instead-of-english-how-can-i-fix/355113#355113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site displays correctly on Firefox, so I think that your problem is font corruption in Chrome or in Windows.

A look in the site's css file shows this line :

```
body{font:13px/1.231 "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Segoe,"Segoe UI","Segoe WP",Calibri,Arial,clean,sans-serif;*font-size:small;}
```

As the fonts are tried by order, and as I don't think that the second entry of Helvetica can be corrupted without you noticing it, then you might have a bad font named "Helvetica Neue". Try to search for it in Control Panel -> Fonts.

Otherwise, I would suggest to completely uninstall Chrome using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), ensuring that all its directories were deleted, then reinstalling.

Comment: Fixed it by downloading the default fonts here: http://www.withsteps.com/404/how-i-restored-my-windows-7-default-fonts.html and re-installing them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Click the Wrench icon, then go to Tools > Encoding.  Try changing the encoding and see if that works.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I use UTF8 and you'll be surprised how many websites botch that :(

Comment: I dont know what to change it to, I've tried UTF8, Western, etc. Nothing is working.